# Name [services] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [services]

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, tomcat8

I was trying to migrate a war deployed in jboss to tomcat 8. I am facing the below exception while loading my application context xml. This was working in jboss. (Had Same issue with dataSource, but it got fixed when I configured `<GlobalNamingResources/>` settings in context.xml.)

Application context has

```
..
<jee:jndi-lookup id="txnService" jndi-name="services/TxnService"
        lazy-init="true" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="mailService" jndi-name="services/MailService"
        lazy-init="true" expected-type="com.tone.mailservice.MailService" />
..
```

And error:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [services/MailService] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [services].
```

and

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txnService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [services/TxnService] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [services].
```

I can see the TxnService class has the following code.

```
public abstract interface TxnService
{
  public static final String JNDI_NAME = "services/TxnService";
  ..
}
```

This class is inside a jar and i have that jar inside the lib folder.
I have tried giving java:/comp/env/services/TxnService and java:/comp/env/services/MailService instead. But still same issue.

Full trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [services/MailService] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [services].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [services/MailService] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [services].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:816)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 54 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txnService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [services/TxnService] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [services].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:720)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:356)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4940)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5250)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [services/TxnService] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [services].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:816)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 51 more
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439421/java-jndi-name-java   .
Seems some issue in naming JNDI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be a JNDI lookup related issue.

Actually, I am trying to provide a fulfill procedure for JBoss to Tomcat migration. Here I have not given the specific answer. Please follow the procedure. After that, if any issue arise, we would start further discussion.

There are mainly 3 areas need to be considered for migration between jboss and tomcat8.

1. Common libraries,
2. Data source configutation,
3. JNDI bindings and basic server configuration

### Common libraries:

**For Tomcat:**

Apache Tomcat stores the common libraries into the CATALINE_HOME/lib folder.

**For JBoss:**

> ```
> JBoss AS release ==== Path for common libs
> 4.x ================= JBOSS_HOME/server/[server-name]/lib
> 5.x - 6.x============ JBOSS_HOME/common/lib
> 7.x ================= JBOSS_HOME/modules
> ```

### Resource Link:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7

---

### Data Source Configuration

If you use Oracle as database then

**For Tomcat**

A Datasource is configured in the context.xml file of Tomcat:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/oracledb"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username="scott"
    password="tiger"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
    maxActive="10"
    maxIdle="2"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="30"
    maxWait="5000"
    logAbandoned="true"
    accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"/>
```

then, you should add your JDBC driver into CATALINA_HOME/lib folder

**For JBoss:**

> ```
> JBoss AS release ======== Path for data source
> 4.x - 5.x - 6.x  ======== datasource-ds.xml file into JBOSS_HOME/server/[server-name]/deploy
> 7.x ===================== datasource-ds.xml file into JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments or as a module into JBOSS_HOME/modules
> ```

---

### JNDI bindings and basic server configuration

In JNDI binding, code related changing should be required in tomcat. JNDI binding can be done in 2 ways.

1. Using lookup code
2. Using the @Resource annotation (javax.annotation.Resource) instead of the lookup code

**Using lookup code**
We can look up the configured JNDI DataSource using Java code as follows:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/UsersDB");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

After obtaining the connection, we can use it as trivial JDBC code:

And then

```
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "select username, email from users";
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
// iterates over the result set...
```

**Using the @Resource annotation (javax.annotation.Resource) instead of the lookup code**

It needs to declare a field called dataSource in the servlet like this:

```
@Resource(name = "jdbc/UsersDB")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

Tomcat will look up the specified resource name and inject an actual implementation when it discovers this annotation.

For full source code with example, you can go through this tutorial: [Configuring JNDI DataSource for Database Connection Pooling in Tomcat](http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/configuring-jndi-datasource-for-database-connection-pooling-in-tomcat)

**For JBoss:**

when using JBoss AS 7 you have to choose a JNDI location like java:/ or java:/jboss for your datasources in order to be accepted.  The portable approach for defining data sources is to use a resource reference.

In our example, we need to define into your web.xml for your connection pool:

DB Connection
      jdbc/oracledb
      javax.sql.DataSource
      Container

Alternatively, starting in Java EE 5 (Servlet 2.5), this can be done even easier within your code using the @Resource annotation.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Resource(name = "jdbc/oracledb")
    private DataSource dataSource;
```

Then on the JBoss side define in your jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
 <resource-ref>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/oracledb</res-ref-name>
 <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/oracledb</jndi-name>
 </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

Fine, now your JNDI lookup will work in either environment, without changing one line of code!

---

### Server Configuration

by default both Tomcat and JBoss are delivering http applications on port 8080, chances are that you might need configuring the http port. Here's tomcat's server.xml

```
<Connector port="32080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

### Resource Link:

1. [Tomcat DataSource JNDI Example in Java](http://www.journaldev.com/2513/tomcat-datasource-jndi-example-java)
2. [Tomcat to JBoss migration](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/tomcat-to-jboss-migration)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look!